# how to match two fields in different lists in mongodb for update query

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

I need help please, I have to match two embedded document with their ids
for example my document structure is like this:

```
{
        "id" : "00025",
        "ean" : "01213134325",
        "notify_stock" : NumberLong(10),
        "specs" : [
            {
                "id" : "0005",
                "spec" : [
                    {
                        "lang" : "fr-FR",
                        "text" : "taille"
                    }
                ],
                "value" : [
                    {
                        "lang" : "fr-FR",
                        "text" : "grand"
                    }
                ]
            }]
}
```

i have a file for multi language like this

```
sku_id;spec_id;spec_name;spec_value
00025;0005;size;big
00025;0006;color;black
```

so my query in mongodb is like this:

```
Modifier update query:
{
  "skus.id" : "<string val>",
  "skus.$.specs.id" : "<string val>"
}
Modifier update details:
{
  "$push" : {
    "skus.$.specs.$.spec" : {
      "lang" : "<string val>",
      "text" : "<string val>"
    },
    "skus.$.specs.$.value" : {
      "lang" : "<string val>",
      "text" : "<string val>"
    }
  }
}
```

when i execute this in Pentaho data integration with the step output mongodb, i got an error

```
"Too many positional (i.e. '$') 
        elements found in path 'skus.$.specs.$.spec'"
```